# bag file and tf transformation

Tags: transforms, ros-melodic, rosbag, tf2, tf-static

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

I recorded a bag file of my robot and this bag file contains all the topics. From this data I need to transform messages from laser-scanner to odom frame using the time stamp when the bag created. What i did is I used the tf and tf_static topics and put them in a buffer and then tried to transform between frames  but i am still getting an error :

> [WARN][/G2O_Generator][1568971858.801114]:
> Lookup would require extrapolation
> into the past.  Requested time
> 1568786441.083348989 but the earliest data is at time 1568786624.298866987,
> when looking up transform from frame
> [nav350] to frame [odom]

And this is the part of my code that does this :

```
 import rospy
import rosbag
from world_model_conversions.sensor_msgs_conversions import vector_list_from_cloud_msg
import tf2_ros
import tf
import tf2_py as tf2
import numpy
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from tf2_geometry_msgs import PointStamped
from tf2_sensor_msgs.tf2_sensor_msgs import do_transform_cloud
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, Point, Quaternion


class G2O_Generator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
        self._tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(self._tf_buffer)

    def convert_pointcloud_frame(self, bag_name):
        #fill the buffer with tf and tf_static msgs
        bag = rosbag.Bag(bag_name)
        for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['/tf', '/tf_static']):
            for msg_tf in msg.transforms:
                self._tf_buffer.set_transform(msg_tf,'default_authority')

        bag = rosbag.Bag(bag_name)
        for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['/reflector_cloud']):
            reflector_cloud_msgs = msg
            trans = self._tf_buffer.lookup_transform("odom", reflector_cloud_msgs.header.frame_id,
                                                     reflector_cloud_msgs.header.stamp,
                                                     rospy.Duration(1))
            
            cloud_out = do_transform_cloud(reflector_cloud_msgs, trans)
            print ("pint_cloud", cloud_out)

        bag.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('G2O_Generator')
    m = G2O_Generator()
    m.convert_pointcloud_f
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333487/bag-file-and--tf-transformation/) by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2019-09-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-20**:
If the bag is 'long' (ie: longer than 60 seconds), you may need to increase the length of the buffer.

Otherwise older transforms may have been pruned from your buffer before you get to the part of your script that actually tries to look them up.

**Comment by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on 2019-09-20**:
thank you very much, actually my bag is really big about 193.358534 sec .. the question can the buffer be increased till that length ? if yes would you like to tell me how to increase it ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-20**:\

> my bag is really big about 193.358534 sec

that's only about 3.5 minutes. That's not really that long :). I have bags of several hours, and that is not even very long.

> how to increase it ?

The Python API of `Buffer`, mirrors the C++ one.

You can use the `cache_time` argument of the `Buffer` ctor. See [tf2_ros::Buffer::Buffer(..)](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html#a46295e44f91d05cfe288eac150dcce58).

**Comment by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on 2019-09-20**:
I did do this :

```
self._tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer(cache_time=rospy.Duration(20000))
```

but i am still getting :

```
g2o_file_generator:43: UserWarning: translation should be of type Vector3
  self._tf_buffer.set_transform(msg_tf,'default_authority')
g2o_file_generator:43: UserWarning: rotation should be of type Quaternion
  self._tf_buffer.set_transform(msg_tf,'default_authority')
[WARN][/G2O_Generator][1568982844.054444]: Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1568786441.083348989, but only time 1568785834.687333107 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [nav350] to frame [odom]
```

**Comment by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on 2019-09-20**:
Am I doing something wrong in my code ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-20**:
The `UserWarning` messages are certainly not what I would expect.

I would check that you're feeding the buffer with the correct data types.

**Comment by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on 2019-09-20**:
Actually i think i know what the problem is , /tf_static is static and it is initialized in the beginning in the bag that's why the timestamp is not correct, do you know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this could be solved like this :

```
tf_buffer = tf2_py.BufferCore(rospy.Duration(1000000))
bag = rosbag.Bag(bag)
for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['/tf', '/tf_static']):
    for msg_tf in msg.transforms:
        if topic == '/tf_static':
            tf_buffer.set_transform_static(msg_tf, "default_authority")
        else:
            tf_buffer.set_transform(msg_tf, "default_authority")
return tf_buffer
```

---

Originally posted by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) with karma: 75 on 2019-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hansolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29473/hansolo/) on 2020-06-02**:
Note, in Melodic, BufferCore doesn't have a lookup_transform method. Instead it is named tf_buffer.lookup_transform_core().